# Why does this C3.JS chart not show the timeseries on the X axis?

Tags: angularjs, time-series, c3.js

This chart was rendering normally, but no longer shows the timeseries across the bottom (sorry for the lack of fiddle):

```
        var c3chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: "#TrendChart",
            size: {
                //width: width,
                height: height * 2
            },
            subchart: {
                show: true
            },
            data: {
                x: "x",
                xFormat: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
                columns: [c3dates, c3Current, c3data],
                names: {
                    data1: "Tags",
                    data2: "Originals"
                },
                colors: {
                    data1: 'rgb(46, 155, 46)', // '.chart-edit-line',
                    data2: 'rgb(124, 215, 255)' // 'chart-history-line'
                },
                types: {
                    data1: 'line',
                    data2: 'area'
                },
                axes: {
                    data2: "y",
                    data2: 'y2'
                }
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    show: true,
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        format: '%H:%M',
                        values: [
                            '21/02/2017 00:00', '21/02/2017 01:30', '21/02/2017 03:00', '21/02/2017 04:30',
                            '21/02/2017 06:00', '21/02/2017 07:30', '21/02/2017 09:00', '21/02/2017 10:30',
                            '21/02/2017 12:00', '21/02/2017 13:30', '21/02/2017 15:00', '21/02/2017 16:30',
                            '21/02/2017 18:00', '21/02/2017 19:30', '21/02/2017 21:00', '21/02/2017 22:30',
                            '21/02/2017 00:00'
                        ]
                    },
                    padding: {
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    show: true,
                    min: 0,
                    padding: {
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 0
                    }
                },
                y2: {
                    show: true,
                    min: 0,
                    padding: {
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            zoom: { enabled: true }
        });
```

Comment: i had a similar problem which turned out to be the dynamic height. can you check if your height is scaling properly? size: { height: height * 2}

Comment: Turns out it was the 'axis.x.tick.values' array. Once I updated the code to use real data and not the dummy data populating 'c3current' and 'c3data' the dates in the 'axis.x.tick.values' array were out of sync, so it didn't render them. I wrote some code to match them up and they reappeared.

Comment: @akoya That's a good idea though. I actually had that same problem last week and fixed it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the 'axis.x.tick.values' array must have the same dates as the values in the chart, or there is not anything on the X axis for the chart to render. I used this code to make sure they match up:

```
var timeindices = [
    '21/02/2017 00:00', '21/02/2017 01:30', '21/02/2017 03:00', '21/02/2017 04:30',
    '21/02/2017 06:00', '21/02/2017 07:30', '21/02/2017 09:00', '21/02/2017 10:30',
    '21/02/2017 12:00', '21/02/2017 13:30', '21/02/2017 15:00', '21/02/2017 16:30',
    '21/02/2017 18:00', '21/02/2017 19:30', '21/02/2017 21:00', '21/02/2017 22:30',
    '21/02/2017 00:00'
];
var timeseries = [];
var dateprefix = dataStore[0][0].substring(0, 11);

timeindices.forEach(function (d) {
    timeseries.push(dateprefix + d.substring(11, 16));
});
```

Then I modified the chart constructor this way:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        show: true,
        type: 'timeseries',
        tick: {
            format: '%H:%M',
            values: timeseries
```